# Wordpress - get post content in new div

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to use a post image/thumbnail in one div and the content in a new div on a custom layout. Having trouble trying to get the content after the image to show.

This works in getting my post title and image into the desired layout but is not showing the image caption–

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<header class="entry-header">
    <?php the_title( '<h3 class="title no-underline">', '</h3>' ); ?>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->

<div class="news-images">
<div id="news-swiper" class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" data-caption="">
            <div class="entry-content news-item-copy">
                <?php
                $get_description = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt;
                the_post_thumbnail();
                if(!empty($get_description)){//If description is not empty show the div
                echo '<div class="image-captions">' . get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt . '</div>';
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="news-sharing">
    <?php wpsocialite_markup(); ?>
</div>
```

This is where I am trying to get the remaining post content and having issues.

```
<div class="news-item-copy">    
<?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
    <?php
        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'themeName' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
    ?>
</div>

</article>
```

I've used `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` just to place the content in it's desired location but obviously because it's an excerpt it's not showing the full content. The idea was to place the featured image/thumbnail with caption on top, the social sharing in the middle and the content last.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to replace the_excerpt() with the_content()

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content

Comment: using `the_content()` retrieves the full content of that post including images which I am not looking for since I already have a function calling the desired image above. Thank you for the input though.

Comment: I'd look into using a custom fields plugin. You can have the images in custom fields and the rest of the content separate. https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Answer (score 0):

You re passing thumbnail id inside `get_post`,you have to pass post id not thumbnail id in that function

$get_description = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt;

Or simply echo `the_content();` it will print post content & if you want to display some limited content
then use

`substr(the_content(),0,150)` it will display only 150 character